Compute $\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ using $x=\cosh(u)$ as substitution when $a,b>1$
I know one standard way of computing $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ is using the substitution $x=\sinh(u)$. This yields that $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sinh^{-1}(x)+C$.
If I have the definite integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ where $a,b>1$, then I don't see why the substitution $x=\cosh{u}$ shouldn't work, as $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ exists for all $x\in [a,b]$. Using this substitution I get that $\displaystyle \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\cosh^{-1}(b)-\cosh^{-1}(a)$.
Comparing the answers the two different substitutions produce, one can see that they are different. I would like to understand why.
Taking a concrete example:
$$\int_2^{10} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \sinh^{-1}(10)-\sinh^{-1}(2)\approx 1.55$$
$$\int_2^{10} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \cosh^{-1}(10)-\cosh^{-1}(2)\approx 1.68.$$

$\sin^-1 (\sech (x))+\ sin^-1(\tanh(x) )= \pi/2$

OP’s second substitution is wrong since $1+\cosh^2 x \ne \sinh^2x$

If you do $x=\sinh(u)$, then$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)}}\cosh(u)\,\mathrm du=\mathrm du,$$since $1+\sinh^2(u)=\cosh^2(u)$.
However, if you do $x=\cosh(u)$, then you get$$\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac1{\sqrt{1+\cosh^2(u)}}\sinh(u)\,\mathrm du$$and there is no useful simplification here.
